# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with PCL 1.9

Tags: ros-melodic, pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a problem using PCL 1.9.1 on ubuntu 18.04. The pcl::NormalDistributionTransform works good but a segmentation fault occurs with the pcl::NormalDistributionTransform when I call for the setinputtarget().
Do you have any idea how to handle this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334966/segmentation-fault-(core-dumped)-with-pcl-1.9/) by [lotfishtaine](https://answers.ros.org/users/27094/lotfishtaine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2019-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-09**:
How did you install PCL `1.9.1`, and more importantly: how are you using it in your node(s)? Melodic still only uses `1.8.1` (see [REP 3](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#melodic-morenia-may-2018-may-2023)), so officially there is no support for `1.9.1`.

**Comment by [lotfishtaine](https://answers.ros.org/users/27094/lotfishtaine/) on 2019-10-09**:
I installed PCL `1.9.1` from package and PCL `1.8.1` it comes when I install ros-melodic. btw compiler gives me some warnings like : warning: libpcl_......... .so.1.9, needed by /usr/local/lib/libpcl_segmentation.so, may conflict with libpcl_....... .so.1.8

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-09**:
Ok. That is most likely why you get those `SEGFAULT`s.

Because of ABI problems you cannot just link nodes against PCL `1.9.1`. You'll most likely have to build all ROS PCL interfacing packages from source. I've written something about that in #q289264.

Note that this is not a ROS problem, but something you always need to keep in mind when reusing binary artefacts (such as libraries): if there is no ABI compatibility guarantee, you cannot (re)link different versions into the same binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution which worked for me without building all  ROS PCL interfacing packages from source is :

1. locate the `PCLConfig.cmake` of the appropriate version (in my case version `1.8.1` which is the latest version supported by ros-melodic) by typing in a terminal : `locate PCLConfig.cmake`
2. help cmake find this `PCLConfig.cmake` by adding this line in `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
set(PCL_DIR "/path/to/PCLConfig.cmake/")
```

before this one:

```
find_package(PCL 1.8 REQUIRED)
```

3. delete devel and build folders and rebuild

---

Originally posted by [lotfishtaine](https://answers.ros.org/users/27094/lotfishtaine/) with karma: 76 on 2019-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-10**:
If you're happy we're happy, but please note that you've created a brittle situation where any changes to that file will result in an incorrect configuration of paths and libraries again.